# Custom JComponent bounds are equals to the container dimension

Tags: java, swing, bounds

I am creating a graph with node pointing to others nodes.

I created my own JComponent to create the arrow :

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class GraphicEdge extends JComponent implements MouseListener{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 4474993605950397943L;

private float x1;
private float y1;
private float x2;
private float y2;

private int width;
private int height;

private String identifier;

private Color color = Color.GRAY;
private final int ARR_SIZE = 14;

public GraphicEdge(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2) {
    this.x1 = x1;
    this.y1 = y1;
    this.x2 = x2;
    this.y2 = y2;

    this.addMouseListener(this);
}


public String getIdentifier() {
    return identifier;
}

public void setIdentifier(String identifier) {
    this.identifier = identifier;
}

private void drawArrow(Graphics g1, float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2) {
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) g1.create();

    g.setColor(color);

    // La transformée affine permet d'orienter le dessin par rapport au corps de la flèche
    double dx = x2 - x1, dy = y2 - y1;
    double angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
    int len = (int) Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);

    AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(x1, y1);
    at.concatenate(AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(angle));
    g.transform(at);

    // Permet de lisser le dessin
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    // Dessin de la tête de la flèche
    Stroke tempStroke = g.getStroke();
    g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(4.0f));
    g.drawLine(0, 0, len - ARR_SIZE, 0);
    g.setStroke(tempStroke);
    g.fillPolygon(new int[] {len, len-ARR_SIZE, len-ARR_SIZE, len},
                  new int[] {0, - Math.round(ARR_SIZE / 2), Math.round(ARR_SIZE / 2), 0}, 4);

    // Placement d'un rectangle arrondi pour écrire la charge du lien
    at = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(- angle);
    g.transform(at);


    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    if(x1 > x2 && y1 > y2){
        g.fillRoundRect(- Math.round((x1 - x2) / 2) - 20, - Math.round((y1 - y2) / 2) - 20, 40, 20, 10, 10);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.drawString("10.8k", - ((x1 - x2) / 2) - 20 + 5, - ((y1 - y2) / 2) - 10 + 5);
        width = Math.round(x1 - x2);
        height = Math.round(y1 - y2);
    }
    else if(x1 > x2 && y1 < y2){
        g.fillRoundRect(- Math.round((x1 - x2) / 2) - 20, Math.round((y2 - y1) / 2) + 20, 40, 20, 10, 10);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.drawString("10.8k", - ((x1 - x2) / 2) - 20 + 5, - ((y1 - y2) / 2) + 10 - 5);
        width = Math.round(x1 - x2);
        height = Math.round(y2 - y1);
    }
    else if(x1 < x2 && y1 > y2){
        g.fillRoundRect(Math.round((x2 - x1) / 2) - 20, - Math.round((y1 - y2) / 2) + 20, 40, 20, 10, 10);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.drawString("10.8k", ((x2 - x1) / 2) - 20 + 5, - ((y1 - y2) / 2) + 10 - 5);
        width = Math.round(x2 - x1);
        height = Math.round(y1 - y2);
    }
    else if(x1 < x2 && y1 < y2){
        g.fillRoundRect(Math.round((x2 - x1) / 2) - 20, Math.round((y2 - y1) / 2) - 20, 40, 20, 10, 10);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.drawString("10.8k", ((x2 - x1) / 2) - 20 + 5, ((y2 - y1) / 2) - 10 + 5);
        width = Math.round(x2 - x1);
        height = Math.round(y2 - y1);
    }
}

public void setColor(Color color){
    this.color = color;  
}

public void setLoad(float loadPercentage){
    if(loadPercentage > 0.01 && loadPercentage <= 0.1){
        setColor(Color.MAGENTA.darker());
    }
    else if(loadPercentage > 0.1 && loadPercentage <= 0.5){
        setColor(Color.BLUE.darker());
    }
    else if(loadPercentage > 0.5 && loadPercentage <= 1){
        setColor(Color.CYAN);
    }
    else if(loadPercentage > 1 && loadPercentage <= 5){
        setColor(Color.GREEN);
    }
    else if(loadPercentage > 5 && loadPercentage <= 10){
        setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    }
    else if(loadPercentage > 10 && loadPercentage <= 50){
        setColor(Color.ORANGE);
    }
    else if(loadPercentage > 50 && loadPercentage <= 100){
        setColor(Color.RED);
    }
    else{
        setColor(Color.GRAY);
    }

    repaint();
}

public void setCoords(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2){
    this.x1 = x1;
    this.y1 = y1;
    this.x2 = x2;
    this.y2 = y2;
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){     
    drawArrow(g, x1, y1, x2, y2);
}

@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(width, height);
}

@Override
public Dimension getMaximumSize() {
    return new Dimension(width, height);
}

@Override
public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
    return new Dimension(width, height);
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println(this.getIdentifier());
}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {};

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

The following code add the arrow in the panel :

```
String identifier = label.substring(1, label.indexOf("$$$"));
GraphicEdge graphicEdge1 = new GraphicEdge(nodeSourcePos[0], nodeSourcePos[1], posX, posY);
graphicEdge1.setIdentifier(identifier);
graphEdges.add(graphicEdge1);
add(graphicEdge1);                  
validate();
```

The problem is that when I click wherever in my container, the mouseClicked event of my GraphicEdge is called.

So, I logged the bounds of my GraphicEdge, I got this : 
x:0 y:0 width:940 height:520

Which are the dimensions of my JPanel containing the graph.
So naturally, the only clickable item is the last added on the graph.

How can I fix this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

When doing custom painting you should override the `getPreferredSize()` method to return the `Dimension` of your component so layout managers know the size of the component.

Comment: You are overriding the width/height in your painting code. That is not the way it is done. The layout manager needs to know the sizes, before the component is ever painted. I'm not sure what happens with code like this.

Comment: Oh, width and height are already existing attributes ?
Because I created my own attributes to calculate W/H

Comment: Ok, I was reading the JComponent API and here is what I found : JComponent has inherited fields from the ImageObserver interface, but they are called WIDTH and HEIGHT, so **I am not overriding anything at all**.

Comment: @Kaijiro You are changing the values of your "width and height" variables in the painting code. This should NOT be done. The painting methods are for painting only, not for calculating the width/height of your component.